# Проблема с Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

В общем,  `justify-content:space-between` не работает на всю ширину блока. Во всем шаблоне, где бы я не использовал его, будет тоже самое. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: проблема]

Comment: дайте ссылку пожалуйста

Comment: А во что обернуты ваши блоки? Случайно не в флекс контейнеры?

Comment: Даже если во флекс-контейнер то ничего в этом страшного нет

Comment: Позже дам ссылку, у меня все на локальной машине сейчас

Comment: @АзаматШарафутдинов Как это нет? Элемент будет занимать ширину по контенту, если ему явно не задать ширину... Что собственно и сделали в ответе..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так, нужно для `ul` задать и ширину ему дать `100%`

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
  <li>Пункт 2</li>
  <li>Пункт 3</li>
  <li>Пункт 4</li>
  <li>Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, напрямую все работает :3

Comment: Тогда поставьте  пожалуйста галочку, если вопрос решен